# How to read the request param values in spring using HTTPServletRequest

Tags: java, spring, http, url

I want to read the requestParams data from the url using HttpServletRequest

```
http://localhost:8080/api/type?name=xyz&age=20
```

The method in my controller will not have @RequestParam defined,it will be just

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> getResponse(
            final HttpServletRequest request) {}
```

I want to read using request only the params not the entire url.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

first, why you are define:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)`
```

?

maybe you should use:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/type", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

and read param :

```
request.getParameter("name");
request.getParameter("age"):
```

Answer (score 5):

xiang is right for your exact question: "I want to read using request only the params"

But why do you want to make it so difficult. Spring supports you, so you do not need to handle the request object by yourself for such common tasks:

I recommend to use

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> getResponse(
    @RequestParam("name") String name
    @RequestParam("age") int age){

    ...
}
```

instead.

@See Spring Reference Chapter [15.3.2.4. Binding request parameters to method parameters with @RequestParam](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
request.getParameter("parameter name")
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
public java.lang.String getParameter(java.lang.String name)
```

From the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/):

> getParameter
>
> String getParameter(String name) Returns the value of a request
>   parameter as a String, or null if the parameter does not exist.
>   Request parameters are extra information sent with the request. For
>   HTTP servlets, parameters are contained in the query string or posted
>   form data. You should only use this method when you are sure the
>   parameter has only one value. If the parameter might have more than
>   one value, use getParameterValues(java.lang.String).
>
> If you use this method with a multivalued parameter, the value
>   returned is equal to the first value in the array returned by
>   getParameterValues.
>
> If the parameter data was sent in the request body, such as occurs
>   with an HTTP POST request, then reading the body directly via
>   getInputStream() or getReader() can interfere with the execution of
>   this method.
>
> Parameters: name - a String specifying the name of the parameter
>   Returns: a String representing the single value of the parameter See
>   Also: getParameterValues(java.lang.String)